# JCarousel next button doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

If I click on next button my carousel looks messy and doesn't work properly. These are the code lines from jcarousel.responsive.js:

```
(function($) {
$(function() {
    var jcarousel = $('.jcarousel');

    jcarousel
        .on('jcarousel:reload jcarousel:create', function () {
            var width = jcarousel.innerWidth();

            jcarousel.jcarousel('items').css('width', width + 'px');
        })
        .jcarousel({
            wrap: 'circular'
        });

    $('.jcarousel-control-prev')
        .jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=1'
        });

    $('.jcarousel-control-next')
        .jcarouselControl({
             target: '+=1'
         });

    $('.jcarousel-pagination')
        .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        })
        .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        .on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        })
        .jcarouselPagination({
            perPage: 1,
            item: function(page) {
                return '<a href="#' + page + '">' + page + '</a>';
            }
        });
});
})(jQuery);
```

If I comment these lines:

```
  $('.jcarousel-control-next')
        .jcarouselControl({
             target: '+=1'
         });
```

, it seems that my carousel works properly, but my next button then works like a link, opening the page that is showing in this moment, in a new window. What is the problem?

Comment: could u provide a fiddle mate..??

Comment: Are there any JS errors if you uncomment these lines?